# Button_Click() fires twice if placed in the group box

Tags: c#, desktop-application, buttonclick, groupbox

I am new to desktop application development.

I have a search button through which the grid is filled from the database records.

First I put the button in the group box and debugged the program and found that the `click` event was firing twice. Then I placed same button out of the text box and found that the event is getting fired only once.

My `Button_Click()` event contains the following code:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = null;

    if (txtBillNo.Enabled && txtBillNo.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
    {
        query = "Select BillNo,PartyName,City,State,FORMAT(BillDt,'dd-mm-yyyy')as Dt from BillMaster where BillNo=" + Convert.ToInt32(txtBillNo.Text.Trim());
        FillGrid(query);
    }

    else if (txtName.Enabled && txtName.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
    {
        query = "Select BillNo,PartyName,City,State,FORMAT(BillDt,'dd-mm-yyyy')as Dt from BillMaster where UCASE(PartyName) like '" + txtName.Text.Trim().ToUpper() + "'";
        FillGrid(query);
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Value First");
        if (rdbName.Enabled)
        {
            txtName.Focus();     
        }
        else if (rdbBillNo.Enabled)
        {
            txtBillNo.Focus();  
        }               
    }                 
}
```

The event handler is bound in the Form_Load() event using:

`btnSearch.Click+=new EventHandler(btnSearch_Click);`

What should I do to fire the click event after placing the button in the group box.
Please help.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there isn't also a subscription to the event happening in the Designer.CS file?

Comment: That was my thought too @MatthewWatson....

Comment: Yes Sir, I am sure for that because in the [Design] form when I double click on the search button. It lets me to write code in ` private void btnSearch_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)` block. @MatthewWatson

Comment: @RiyazKalva Fair enough - although I'd have a peek in Designer.cs just in case...

Comment: I have also checked in the Designer.cs and not found that no event handler assigned for button.

Answer (score 1):

I think the contents of your `btnSearch_Click` is irrelevant. I am almost sure that `btnSearch.Click` is assigned twice. Once in your `Form_Load` and possibly somewhere else, perhapse in your code-behind file?

Comment: I have also checked in the Designer.cs and not found that no event handler assigned for button. @Martin Mulder